# How can I read the files from a tar command into an array using BASH?

Tags: arrays, linux, bash

Using a BASH script, how can I execute a tar command and read the output (the list of files) into an array?

I've tried a number of things, including:

```
fileNames=`tar xvfz ${compressedFile} | readarray`

tar xvfz ${compressedFile} | readarray fileNames

readarray fileNames < tar xvfz ${compressedFile}

files=`tar xvfz ${compressedFile}'
readarray fileNames < ${files}

readarray fileNames < `echo ${files}`
```

I've tried with and without the backquote (grave accent) and I've tried using t as an option on the tar.gz file. I was trying to accomplish this without sending the output to a file and then reading the file, but I guess that's my fall-back plan (though I haven't tried it yet).

The closest I've come is:

```
echo ${fileNames} | readarray fileNames
```

but this creates only 1 item in the array and it contains all of the file names. Argh. :)

Anyone know how to accomplish this (seemingly) easy task?

V

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should create array with contents of tar file:

```
IFS=$'\n' declare -a fileNames=($(tar tzf "$compressedFile"))
```

This is assuming your file names inside tar file don't have newlines.

Comment: You're aware that that command will permanently alter `IFS`, right? That may have some interesting consequences in the rest of the script.

Comment: Hmm that's right. OP can do: `IFS=$'\n' declare -a fileNames=($(tar tzf "$compressedFile"))` to avoid mangling `IFS` in shell env.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong with using `readarray` (now called `mapfile`), but you need to execute the command in the current shell, not a subshell. So

```
tar tzf "$compressedFile" | readarray -t fileNames
```

won't work, because `readarray` is being executed in a subshell, as a result of the pipe. Instead you need to redirect stdin from [*process substitution*](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution):

```
readarray -t filenames < <(tar tzf "$compressedFile")
```

Note the `-t` flag to `readarray`. Without it, the values in the array would contain trailing newlines.

Comment: Is it intended that you e**x**tract the tar file?

Comment: @cyrus: probably better to ask OP, but I'm going to guess "no". Edited and thanks.